# c# WebClient Downloading a Zip Corrupts it

Tags: c#, download, zip, webserver

Downloading Zip files with webclient seems to not be working properly for me, once downloaded and saved the zip file comes up as invalid or corrupted, opening with a zip reader. However the source zip file seems to be fine, its a valid zip.

Download code:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL), downloadZipFilename);
        }
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //unzip
        using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(currentTemporaryDownloadFileUrl))
        {
            zipFile.ExtractAll(currentTargetFileUrl);
        }
        File.Delete(currentTemporaryDownloadFileUrl);
        DownloadFinished(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("File finished downloading.");
    }
```

The zip extract comes up as corrupt.

Server code:

```
 //send file
                    e.Response.Connection.Type = HttpServer.Headers.ConnectionType.Close;
                    byte[] buffer = ReadFile(filePath);
                    e.Response.Body.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Readfile on server:

```
public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
        {
            // this method is limited to 2^32 byte files (4.2 GB)

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();
                return bytes;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks,
Christian Stewart

Comment: You could be running out of memory in your `ReadFile`.

Comment: Have you compared the downloaded file with the file on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than, inefficiently, loading the ZIP file into memory, then writing it out, how about using

```
e.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

TransmitFile streams directly to the output stream without buffering, thus minimising memory consumption.

Comment: Ah, I see, streaming the file on the server. Let me see about using this.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to figure out how to use this, because the response variable does not have TransmitFile available on it. I'm using HttpServer, its a class from somewhere, I just dont remember where :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the `WebClient` call you use `downloadZipFilename` while int the `Completed` method you use `currentTemporaryDownloadFileUrl`... could it be that the `Completed` method tries to unzip some other file and the downloaded one ?

Your server code supports only <= 2 GB (Int32 is an alias for int which is signed!)... is the file perhaps bigger than 2 GB ?
If the file is bigger then your server codes sends for the "rest" (above 2 GB) all bytes as 0x00 which definitely makes the ZIP corrupt...

Comment: Hi, It is much less than 2GB, only a few kilobytes for test. The two strings should be the same, they are set as thus earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you de-couple the server transmission from the client read-and-unpack.  that way you can isolate any problems that arise.

Make sure the server "create and transmit zip file" thing works properly. Try hitting the server from a browser, make sure you can unpack the zip file successfully.  Then add in the C# client, to download-and-unpack the zip file programmatically.

Comment: What I eventually ended up doing here (just realized I never accepted an answer here) was that I packed each file, sent it, then unpacked it - the problem here was that I was keeping it in the memory. Instead I now have it just download the file to a temporary folder then extract from there.